# Como exportar a pdf algunos campos de una tabla html con jsPDF

Tags: html, jquery, jsp, jspdf

Estoy usando JSPDF para exportar una tabla a pdf , pero la tabla que estoy exportando tiene una columna con botones de acción, el problema es que al exportar la tabla también se exportan los botones y quisiera saber como puedo exportar solo algunas columnas de la tabla para así exportar la tabla menos sin la columna de los botones.

Aca está la tabla

```
<div class="panel-body panel panel-primary" id="content">
                <form method="POST" action="AdministrarReservasServlet">
                    <button type="submit" name="btnMostrarReservas" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Mostrar</button>
                    <button type="button" name="btnVolver" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="location.href='barraCentral.jsp'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Volver</button>
                      <br><br><br>
                        <table class="table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="resultado">
                            <thead>    
                                <tr class="">
                                    <th class="btn-info">N° Reserva</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Origen</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Destino</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Origen Vuelo</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Piezas</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Kilos</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Volumen</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Estado</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style='display:none'>Notas</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Fecha Creación</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Fecha Embarque</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Tipo</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Prioridad</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Forma Pago</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Tarifa</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Tipo Moneda</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Rut Cliente</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Nombre Cliente</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Telefono Cliente</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Direccion Cliente</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Email Cliente</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Acción</th>
                                    <!--<th class="btn-info">Cliente</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Usuario</th>
                                    <th class="btn-info">Acción</th>-->

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
 <%               
     try
          {
              for(int i=0; i<adminReservas.size(); i++)
                  {
                   out.println("<tr>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"</td>");
                    //out.println("<td><input type='text' value='"+adminReservas.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"' class='input-sm form-control' size='5' readonly='readonly'></td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getDestinoReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTotalPiezasReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTotalKilosReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTotalVolumenReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getEstadoReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getNotaReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getFechaCreacionReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getFechaEmbarqueReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTipoReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getPrioridadReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTipoTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTipoMonedaReserva()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getRutCliente()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"+adminReservas.get(i).getNombreCliente()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getTelefonoCliente()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getDireccionCliente()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+adminReservas.get(i).getEmailCliente()+"</td>");
                      out.println("<td>"
                                + "<button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'></button>"
                                + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAdministrarReservaEliminarReserva'></button>"
                              + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' onclick=location.href='detalleReserva.jsp'></button>"
                              + "</td>");
                                            //out.println("<td><a type='button'  href='modificarReservas.jsp?id='"+adminReservas.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"' '  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open' style='font-size:19px'></button></td>");
                                            //out.println("<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_guia' class='form-control checkbox' value='"+adminReservas.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"'></td>");
                                        }   
         }
     catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
         {
                     ex.getMessage();
                   //out.print("<input type='text' value='"+ex.getMessage()+"'>");
                     out.print("</tr>");
         }

 %>
        </tbody>   
        </table>
```

```
</div>
```

Aca el codigo jquery para exportar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Export() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('resultado'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Table.pdf");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Acá el botón que ejecuta la función.

```
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="Export()" />
```

Acá el pdf de la tabla exportada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero su ayuda gracias.

Comment: ¿Y si antes de html2canvas haces que esa columna tenga un display none y luego de descargar el archivo regresas a mostrarlo? ¿Funcionará?

Comment: y como quedaría un display none dentro del código de jquery? la verdad tengo poco conocimiento en javascript.

Answer (score 1):

4 cosas:

1) Si te hace falta aprender JavaScript y jQuery, ve directo a la documentación oficial, serán tus nuevas biblias:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn
- https://api.jquery.com/

2) Practica, intenta, haz lo posible para entender los errores, sus motivos e intenta nuevamente resolver el caso.

3) Decir que uno tiene poco conocimiento en algo jamás debe ser limitante, hay que buscar información, leer, practicar, seguir leyendo y seguir practicando, en nuestra carrera de programadores la principal manera de aprender es creyendo que es posible y acto seguido intentando N maneras sin perder el norte.

4) Aquí tienes código, espero te sea de utilidad:

Reemplaza:

```
<th class="btn-info">Acción</th>
```

Por:

```
<th class="btn-info desaparecerTemporalmente">Acción</th>
```

Y también reemplaza:

```
out.println("<td>"
                                + "<button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'></button>"
                                + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAdministrarReservaEliminarReserva'></button>"
                              + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' onclick=location.href='detalleReserva.jsp'></button>"
                              + "</td>");
```

Por:

```
 out.println("<td class='desaparecerTemporalmente'>"
                                + "<button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'></button>"
                                + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAdministrarReservaEliminarReserva'></button>"
                              + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' onclick=location.href='detalleReserva.jsp'></button>"
                              + "</td>");
```

Tu función de exportación se actualiza con un par de líneas extra:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Export() {
        //Seleccionamos TODOS los elementos que tienen esta clase "desaparecerTemporalmente y le damos un display none"
        $(".desaparecerTemporalmente").css("display","none");
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('resultado'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Table.pdf");
            }
        });
        //Ahora que ya fue exportado, regresamos los botones a su sitio:
        $(".desaparecerTemporalmente").css("display","");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: a entiendo a "desaparecerTemporalmente" lo llamas como clase desde las etiquestas th, le dices que desaparezca con la función display-none de css y lo luego la haces aparecer con la función display. a ok lo voy a probar gracias.

Comment: Hola el código no me funciono, gracias seguiré intentando.

Comment: me sorprende que no haya funcionado, en tu código tienes  `<th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Telefono Cliente</th><th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Direccion Cliente</th><th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Email Cliente</th>`y no es mostrado al momento de generar dicho documento

Comment: por cierto @SimónPereiraVigouroux actualicé la respuesta agregando comillas simples en vez de dobles en esta parte: `out.println("<td class='desaparecerTemporalmente'>"` . Debería funcionar el código, ¿qué comportamiento tiene?